# Can't change opencart default theme

Tags: themes, opencart-3

I have recently installed opencart successfully with default theme.Now i going to change another theme.i have purchased theme from theme forest Verito_OC theme.then i did the following steps

1)unzip theme and move to **catalog/view/theme**

then open admin dashboard and
2)**Extensions-> Extensions->theme->theme directory**
[image]

But bad luck i can't change theme.Please help me.

Comment: What happens? Any error messages available?

Comment: @zgue:no error..but i can't change theme.

Comment: Is there an admin folder inside your theme package?

Comment: @DigitCart-nop..there is noadmin folder inside theme package

Answer (score 0):

Installing theme in opencart 3.x

(a)upload theme.ocmod.zip via opencart installer

(b)goto extensions > themes >click edit (choose your theme and enable it).

(c)goto system > setting > click edit button > General tab ,change themes from default to your installed theme from dropdown.

(d)goto extensions > modification > select all >click refresh

(e)goto dashboard > click setting button and clear the cache there